# How to select all where column data begins with certain numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
studentID   lastName  firstName
08422567    Brown     Susan
10356844    Black     Roger
10659475    White     Steven
09463729    Grey      Naomi
```

I am trying to select all students whose ID begins with 10, so basically Roger and Steven.

Here are examples of what I was trying:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentID='10356844' AND  studentID='10659475'
SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentID='10356844,10659475'
```

Would I need to use regular expressions for this, surely there must be a simpler way to run a query like this? In the future there may be 100 number beginning with 10, I cannot add all of these to a query, and the difficulty of this is why I ask this question here, in order to get the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a regular expression, but `WHERE studentID LIKE '10%'`.  The `%` is a wildcard, so it will match any student whose ID begins with 10.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, very simple! :) I will accept this answer in 11 minutes! :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This would never succeed:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentID='10356844' AND  studentID='10659475'
```

because there is no row that has both of those values of studentID.  It's impossible.  What you meant to do was:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentID='10356844' OR  studentID='10659475'
```